# Next JS API fetching on SSR component only returns first object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm having an issue with fetching some data from a server using Vercel's postgres server. Navigating to the endpoint `Localhost:3000/api/records` returns the entire database, as desired.

```
{"body":
  [{"id":1,"username":"Carson","timer":60,"difficulty":0,"wpm":85}, 
  {"id":2,"username":"Pogchamp","timer":60,"difficulty":0,"wpm":85},
  {"id":3,"username":"test","timer":90,"difficulty":3,"wpm":70}]
}
```

But, using a function inside an SSR component only seems to be returning the first object in the database like so:

`{body: [ { id: 1, username: 'Carson', timer: 60, difficulty: 0, wpm: 85 } ]}`

Is there something I'm doing obviously wrong here? I'm pretty new to API routing. Here's my endpoint `route.ts` in the directory `app/api/records`:

```
export async function GET() {
  try {
    const data: Record[] = await prisma.record.findMany();
    return NextResponse.json({ body: data });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

and my SSR component:

```
async function getRecords() {
  const res = await fetch("${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/records");
  if (!res.ok) {
    console.log("ERROR");
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch records");
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default async function LeaderBoard() {
  const data = await getRecords();
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      {data.body.map((rec: Record, idx: number) => (
        <p key={idx}>{rec.username}</p>
      ))}
    </div>);
}
```

I've tested by going to the endpoint itself, returning the correct result but fetching from the endpoint seems to not be working.

Comment: Have you tried to await the call to `res.json()` in your `getRecords()` function? I'm not sure it can solve the issue but it's worth trying.

Comment: @canta2899 I gave it try and it didn't seem to fix it. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Yeah seems right, you're awaiting the call to getRecords in LeaderBoard so the promise is resolved there. Have you also tried to render your data inside the component (using something `data.body.map((e) => <div key={e.id}>{e.username}</div>)`)) and check if it renders only the first element?

Comment: @canta2899 yes, I actually deleted it just to make it more simple. I looks pretty much exactly as you have it: 

`<div> {data.body.map((rec: Record, idx: number) => (<p key={idx}>{rec.username}</p> ))}</div>`

I'll throw this code back into the question so other's can see.

Comment: Not sure if it will work but you can try adding "Content-Type": "application/json" to the headers of the fetch request

Comment: @ArjisChakraborty Thank you! This fixed it! Not sure if I can accept comments as answers? Also why would this fix the issue, if you might know exactly? Is it just specifying that the payload is JSON?

Comment: Yeah you are pretty much just letting fetch know that you are specifying a JSON payload and you are expecting the response to be JSON as well. Maybe the reason why you were just seeing one object out of 3 in total is because fetch wasn't able to parse the JSON response. It was totally a wild guess but as they say, if it works, it works!